# Limit normalised confusion matrix to 2 decimal points

Tags: python-3.x

I am displaying a normalised confusion matrix as below:

```
[[0.9        0.         0.0106383  0.         0.        ]
[0.         0.83673469 0.05319149 0.01801802 0.04347826]
[0.         0.04081633 0.87234043 0.09009009 0.        ]
[0.         0.         0.14893617 0.83783784 0.17391304]
[0.         0.         0.04255319 0.04504505 0.60869565]]
```

I want to only show 2 decimal places.

Here is my code for the normalised confusion matrix:

```
# Confusion Matrix
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted)
conf_mat_norm = conf_mat / conf_mat.astype(np.float).sum(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method, it worked for me. Please up vote this answer if it works for you.

```
conf_mat_norm= np.around(conf_mat.astype('float') / conf_mat.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis], decimals=2)
```